# restore db from entity framework connection

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, database-restore

I have to implement an administration web procedure using asp.net mvc 4 and entity framework.

In this procedure I let the user to execute backup and restore of some sql server databases.

I don't have problems with the backup procedure, but I have some issues with the restore procedure.

I think a good sql command sequence is this:

```
"ALTER DATABASE [" + prj.Denominazione_Db + "] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"

"RESTORE DATABASE [" + prj.Denominazione_Db + "] FROM DISK = '" + fileDaRestorare +"'"

"ALTER DATABASE [" + prj.Denominazione_Db + "] SET MULTI_USER"

"GO"
```

I set the db in single user mode, restore, and reset in multi user mode.
  I have done a few experiments using the entity framework connection, but I receive a few exceptions, like 
I cannot use the alter database command in a multi-command statement
or
Cannot invoke the alter database command inside a transaction.

If i try to execute to restore directly I receive the message that cannot execute restore inside a transaction.

Do you know ho can I invoke this sequence of commands using the entity framework connection?

thanks,
  luca

Comment: any way you should start with a "use tempdb". I would be very surprised if you can restore a database being connected on it

Comment: have you tried `using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)){ }`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you dont use EF for restore.
Even accessing Context.Database. can trigger activity you arent expecting.
eg
[opened/closed connection ? and EF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/26/exception-from-dbcontext-api-entityconnection-can-only-be-constructed-with-a-closed-dbconnection.aspx)

Suggest you read 
[Context database class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)
before you decide on this solution.

I deliberately DONT use EF for such DB actions Only

```
SqlConnectionFactory 
SqlConnection
SqlCommand
```